# Opening a byte stream file using asp.net mvc

Tags: file, asp.net-mvc-2, filecontentresult

Im my asp.net mvc application I have a

enclosing the thumb image of the file in an aspx page loaded in an iframe. I want to open the file with an Open/Save dialogbox. The file is uploaded to the database in image datatype.
My aspx page has the following html in it:

```
<li class="thumpimage">
                        <%=Html.Hidden("attachmtId", item.ILDAttachmentId) %>
                        <img src="<%=imgurl %>" alt="test" height="81" width="76" />
                        <span class="thumb_descrp">
                            <%=item.ILDAttachmentName %></span></li>
```

The jquery part is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".thumpimage").click(function() {
            var attchmtId = $("#attachmtId").val();
            alert(attchmtId);
            $.post('/Instruction/OpenInstnDoc', { attchId: attchmtId });
        });
    });
```

And the function in the controller is

```
 public ActionResult OpenInstnDoc(int attchId)
    {

        Attachment objAttach = new Attachment();
        objAttach = objAttach.GetAttachmentById(attchId);

        byte[] theData = objAttach.BinaryFile;
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", theData.Length.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + objAttach.AttachmentName + "");
        return File(theData, objAttach.MineType);
    }
```

I am not able open the file. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What is `File`? (Clearly not `System.IO.file` – it is a static class.) What error/exception are you getting?

Comment: file is FileContentResult File(byte[] fileContents, string contentType). Am not getting any exception. Also no Open/Save dialog box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use ajax to stream file content to the browser and expect to be prompted with a file open/save dialog. Instead of the call to $.post, try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".thumpimage").click(function() {
        var attchmtId = $("#attachmtId").val();
        alert(attchmtId);
        //$.post('/Instruction/OpenInstnDoc', { attchId: attchmtId });
        window.location.href = "/Instruction/OpenInstnDoc/" + attchmtId;
    });
});
```

Comment: I got an Object reference error in the page loaded to the iframe.

Comment: You are receiving a javascript error?  I updated my post to include the full document.ready function.  Is the alert popping up?